# Mi select2 tarda mucho en cargar los datos en mi formulario

Tags: javascript, php

Amigos(as) como están, soy nueva en el tema de Php :( les comento que tengo un problema con mi control select2, mando a llamar mis datos atraves de un Select2 , pero creo que la cantidad de datos a mostrar es muy grande y tarda en visualizarse. ¿Alguna Solución?

*Mi controlador*

```
    case "combo_localidad":
        $datos = $tramites->lugar_localidad();
        if(is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0){/* 
            $html = "<option>Seleccionar una opción</option>"; */
            foreach($datos as $row)
            {
                $html.="<option value='".$row['id_localidad']."'>".$row['localidad']."</option>";
            }
            echo $html;
        }
    break;
```

*Mi modelo*

```
 public function lugar_localidad(){
        $conectar = parent::conexion();
        parent::set_names();
        $sql="SELECT * from tm_localidad;";
        $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
        $sql->execute();
        return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
    }
```

*Mi vista *

```
<form method="post" id="cliente_form">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label semibold" for="id_localidad">Localidad</label>
        <select class="select2" id="id_localidad" name="id_localidad">
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
     <button type="submit" name="action" value="add" class="btn btn-inline btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-right"><span class="ladda-label">Guardar</span><span class="ladda-spinner"></span><div class="ladda-progress" style="width: 0px;"></div></button>
</div>
```

*Mi método POST que llama a mi controlador*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//llamamos a nuestro servicio de controller
$.post("../../controller/tramites.php?op=combo_localidad", function (data, status) {
    $('#id_localidad').html(data);
});
```

});

Comment: Buenas. Con respecto a tu pregunta, para que sea aceptada y recibir buena respuestas, primero te sugiero que hagas el [tour], para conocer este sitio (que mas adelante te va ser muy útil para tus trabajos de codificación y buscar soluciones); luego hacer una pequeña lectura sobre [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea presentable y mejorada, no agregues mas de dos imágenes sino mas bien, códigos. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar tu código seleccionando **{ }** justo arriba del edito donde escribes (aquí en Stackoverflow).

Comment: Muchas gracias Narciso Aifuz, lo tomare en cuenta.

Comment: ¿Qué cantidad de datos estás cargando? Si realmente son muchos registros, en vez de `select2` tal vez deberías usar un script de autocompletado.

Comment: Si solo necesitas dos campos de esa tabla, no los saques todos, quizas ayude, cambiando la consulta por `SELECT id_localidad, localidad from tm_localidad`, y si estan repetidos usa DISTINCT, y son muchos mejor que te crees un indice con esos campos para realizar la consulta más rapidamente.

Comment: @Triby, son mas de 29,000 datos. ¿Un script de autocompletado ? Te refieres como un scroll infinito?

Comment: @masterguru no mi amigo, no diferencia en gran manera , ya que solo tiene esos dos campos la tabla.

Comment: Ok, no lo sabia, tenia que probar :-)  En cuanto a lo de triby se refiere a un script en javascript que se ponga a la escucha del tecleo en un input (con addEventListener por ejemplo) y que conforme va escribiendo va lanzando peticiones ajax a un PHP que va lanzando consultas más delimitadas a tu tabla y mostrando resultados. No seria un select propiamente dicho, pero es que un select de 29000 datos es infumable.

Comment: @berenice, ya que estás usando jQuery, tal vez quieras probar la extensión [autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/451000/54039) podría servirte como ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

noto un par de cosas en tu codigo que se podrian mejorar a nivel de arquitectura. Si bien creo que la repuesta de masterguru puede servir, va a depender de la cantidad de datos que traigas.

No se la flexibilidad de tu trabajo o de los datos que tengas pero por ejemplo si esas localidades estan relacionadas con regiones podrias pedirle al usuario que primero seleccione una region y luego las localidades, no es lo mismo traer todos los paises del mundo a traerlos dependiendo el continente que eligas.

Otra cosa que puede mejorar la performance es que noto que en el php tenes un case y estas usando el modelo MVC. Yo trabajé y trabajo mucho con ese modelo y te dejo un par de tips:

Crear archivos php solo para la query que vas a hacer o sea un archivo por consulta y dentro de ese archivo se hace la query y el resultado lo metes dentro de un array con indices para luego por medio de json_encode($array) pasas los datos a js (que deberia ser el controlador no php) por ejemplo:

```
    //se supone que antes haces la consulta y tenes el resultado en una variable x yo la llame $result, pero solo eso, la consulta, el archivo de conexion y si mandas parametros con POST para busqueda tambien.
while($result){
  $json[]=array({'id' =>$result['id_localidad'], 'nombre'=> utf8_encode($result['nombre']}));
} 

    //lo que pongas entre corchetes es el alias o nombre de columna de la query
        //el utf8_encode es para que no tengas problemas si hay acentos o ñ, podes no ponerlo si queres
   

echo json_encode($json);
```

con esto logras dos cosas, primero un php mas limpio y segundo dejas de usar un lenguaje que es de servidor para imprimir o procesar cosas que deberia hacer js y html.

Luego, en el controlador (js) donde haces el $.post, ahi es donde decodificas el JSON que te envia php y agregas los datos. Ya que usas Jquery seria algo asi:

```
$.post("../../controller/tramites.php?op=combo_localidad", function (data, status) {
    let res = JSON.parse(data);
    res.map((e) => $('#id_localidad').append(`<option value=${e.id}>${e.nombre}</option>`))
});
```

como podes notar, uso un bucle para poder llenar el select y que el **e** es un objeto con datos (res es un array que tiene objetos, por eso le podes hacer el map, si fuera solo un objeto no podrias) y que la key coincide con el nombre que le pones en el model (php). De esta forma tambien utilizas el poder del navegador para el procesamiento de los datos y dejas al servidor un poco mas aliviado.

Espero que te sirva, por lo que vi esta bastante bien el codigo te felicito, el tema del rendimiento es algo con lo que siempre vas a tener problemas pero muchas veces es por culpa del mismo servidor o de la arquitectura de la db, por eso hay que rebuscarsela desde el diseño muchas veces para que la consulta sea lo mas filtrada posible.